# Cannot run same class in two instances

Tags: java, multithreading, server, parallel-processing, client

I am trying to connect 2 or more clients to a java server using threads, but when I try to run my class client multiple times it says

> 'Client' is not allowed to run in parallel.
>   Would you like to stop the running one?

I would like to get something like this

edit:

I've noticed that if I run this program in cmd everything works fine, I can connect with 2 or more clients without any problems.

The problem is that I cant do it in intelliJ due to 'parallel' error.

[image]

And my code looks like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {

    private static String[] names = {"Willy", "Felix", "Piotr"};
    private static String[] adjs = {"the gentle", "the un-gentle", "the urbane"};
    private static final int PORT = 9090 ;

    private static ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //utworzenie nowego socketu
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Serwer czeka na polaczenie...");
            //akceptowanie polaczenia
            Socket client = listener.accept();
            System.out.println("S: Polaczono z klientem");
            ClientHandler clientThread = new ClientHandler(client);
            clients.add(clientThread);

            pool.execute(clientThread);
        }



    }

    public static String getRandomName()
    {
        String name = names[(int)(Math.random()*names.length)];
        String adj = adjs[(int)(Math.random()*adjs.length)];
        return name + " " + adj;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 9090;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //tworzenie socketu
        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);

        //buffer za pomoca ktorego client odbiera cos od servera
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        //buffer pobierajacy z klawiatury
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //buffer wysylajacy do servera
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true) {
            //czytanie z klawiatury do zmiennej command
            System.out.println("> ");
            String command = keyboard.readLine();
            //wyslanie zawartosci command do servera
            if(command.equals("quit")) break;
            out.println(command);

            String serverResponse = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server mowi: " + serverResponse);
        }



        //zamkniecie socketow i buffera
        //socket.close();
        //input.close();
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable{

    //zmienne dla socketa i bufferow z dateserver
    private Socket client;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        this.client = clientSocket;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            while (true) {
                String request = in.readLine();
                if (request.contains("name")) {
                    out.println(Server.getRandomName());
                } else {
                    out.println("Type 'tell me a name' to get random name");
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IO exception in client handler");
            System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }finally {
            out.close();
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I have been trying to figure it out what is wrong but can't do nothing about it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running your code, but i didn't get the error, maybe you need to increase the java virtual machine. because my default is 12000 mb

[image]

[image]

to increase the java memory, you can do the next

[Java memory](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/wikihow/index.php/How_to_Increase_Java_Memory_in_Windows)

if it is not function, you need to check the ide, i used netbeans

Comment: Much thanks! I've installed netbeans and it helped, I guess I have messed something in my intellij ide so will try to uninstall it.

Comment: I did it, clicked v button near your post. Is it ok?

Comment: one more question - how did you changed names in console? Its Run(Server) and Run(Client), I got JavaAplication #1, JavaAplication #2 etc

Comment: the ide changed its